# How to get the deepest XML element

Tags: php, xml, xpath

```
<Item>
<BrowseNodes>
    <BrowseNode>
        <BrowseNodeId>3024254031</BrowseNodeId>
        <Name>Tunnelzelte</Name>
        <Ancestors>
            <BrowseNode>
                <BrowseNodeId>3024250031</BrowseNodeId>
                <Name>Zelte</Name>
                <Ancestors>
                    <BrowseNode>
                        <BrowseNodeId>16435151</BrowseNodeId>
                        <Name>Camping & Outdoor</Name>
                        <Ancestors>
                            <BrowseNode>
                                <BrowseNodeId>16435121</BrowseNodeId>
                                <Name>Kategorien</Name>
                                <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>
                                <Ancestors>
                                    <BrowseNode>
                                        <BrowseNodeId>16435051</BrowseNodeId>
                                        <Name>Sport & Freizeit</Name>
                                    </BrowseNode>
                                </Ancestors>
                            </BrowseNode>
                        </Ancestors>
                    </BrowseNode>
                ´</Ancestors>
            </BrowseNode>
        </Ancestors>
    </BrowseNode>
</BrowseNodes>
```

Hi,

I try to get the deepest "Name" element and vlaue (Sport & Freizeit in this case), but it does not work with `xpath()`:

```
$temp=$item->xpath("//Name[last()]");
```

I guess I don't understand how xpath() works..

Does anybody has a hint? The number of "BrowseNode" elements is flexible, so I can't work with a fix path.

Comment: Caveat: Depending on the structure of the actual document, the last `Name` node might not be the most deeply nested, and there might be several `BrowseNode` elements that do not have an `Ancestors` element as a child.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap the `//Name` tag and then get the last item.

```
(//Name)[last()]
```

Answer (score 2):

The "deepest" element could be described as one that has no `Ancestors` child node.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//BrowseNode[not(Ancestors)]/Name)')
);
```

- Fetch any "BrowseNode"
  `//BrowseNode`
- ... without an "Ancestors" child
  `//BrowseNode[not(Ancestors)]`
- ... fetch its "Name" child
  `//BrowseNode[not(Ancestors)]/Name`
- ... cast the first fetched node into string
  `string(//BrowseNode[not(Ancestors)]/Name)`

If the structure is allowed to have multiple `BrowseNode` branches the problem can not be solved with Xpath alone. In this case you will have to fetch the nodes into an array and sort it.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$leafs = array_map(
  function(DOMElement $node) use ($xpath) {
      // fetch name and level
      return [
          'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $node),
          'level' => (int)$xpath->evaluate('count(ancestor::BrowseNode)', $node),
          // keep the node for additional Xpath expressions
          'node' => $node
      ];  
  },
  // get BrowseNode elements without Ancestors
  iterator_to_array(
      $xpath->evaluate('//BrowseNode[not(Ancestors)]')
  )
);

// sort array by level descending
usort(
    $leafs,
    function($a, $b) {
        // compare level
        $result = -($a['level'] <=> $b['level']);
        // same level -> compare name
        return ($result !== 0) ? $result : strnatcmp($a['name'], $b['name']); 
    }
);

// let's output the leafs to see what has happened
foreach ($leafs as $leaf) {
    var_dump([$leaf['name'], $leaf['level']]);
}
```

By keeping the node in the leaf array you can use additional Xpath expressions to fetch related data. Like all ancestor names:

```
// get the first 
if (count($leafs) > 0) {
    $leaf = $leafs[0];
    var_dump(
        array_map(
            function(DOMElement $node) {
                return $node->textContent;
            },
            // fetch Name of ancestors
            iterator_to_array(
                $xpath->evaluate('ancestor::BrowseNode/Name', $leaf['node'])
            )
        )
    );
}
```